# local variable changes value late

Tags: scope, eval, zsh, local-variables

If I have a function `my-func` like this:

```
my-func(){
    v=$1
    eval $2
}
```

Then this is the Output I get for running `my-func 123 "echo $v"`:

Running it for the first time:

```
#nothing
```

Running it for the second+ time:

```
123
```

If I now run `my-func 789 "echo $v"`, then I get the following output for the first time:

```
123
```

And this for the second+ time:

```
789
```

So, why is the Output delayed by one and how can I fix it?

Comment: "echo $v"is being run first.

Comment: @arundeepchohan Yes, but why? And how can I make it run second?

Comment: You could simply echo $v after v =$1.

Comment: @arundeepchohan ? but isn't that what `my-func`(see top of question) is already doing with `v=$1; eval $2`?

Comment: You are echoing the value before the method starts.

Comment: @arundeepchohan But commenting the `eval` out makes the function not echo anything at all. And wouldn't this echo everything twice then? p.s. `my-func` is the only command that I'm executing, if this is what you mean

Comment: Note that `v` is *not* local; assignments inside a function are global by default.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. @CJK already mentioned this in their answer. I added the `local` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what makes [`arundeep chohan`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9901261/arundeep-chohan) believe that the line at the end of your function is somehow being run before the lines before.  That is not what is happening.

There are two things to remember here:

- Arguments undergo variable expansion on the command-line *before* being sent through to the function; and
- Variables defined inside a functions are, by default, global in scope, so they will be available to the entire shell upon creation, which happens during the first call to the function when execution reaches the line in which the variable is declared.  Unless a variable is also exported, it ceases to exist when the shell process is destroyed, or if it gets unset.

Here's your function definition:

```
my-func(){
    v=$1
    eval $2
}
```

Here's the sequence of commands you entered as described in your question; comments to provide insight to what is happening at the command line before the function receives the arguments; and the output of each printed immediately below:

```sh
$ my-func 123 "echo $v" # my-func 123 "echo "
$ my-func 123 "echo $v" # my-func 123 "echo 123"
123
$ my-func 789 "echo $v" # my-func 123 "echo 123"
123
$ my-func 789 "echo $v" # my-func 123 "echo 789
789
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you. Adding a `\ ` before the `$v` solved it(since the variable expansion now happens when the `eval` is executed)!